# Capturing a certain window using Gstreamer in Windows 10

Tags: windows, gstreamer, screen-capture

In Ubuntu 18.04, I'm able to capture a certain X-Window using [ximagesrc](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/ximagesrc/index.html) element of GStreamer (v1.16) simply by setting the `xid` or `xname`of that window. I want to have the same screen capture functionality in Windows 10. I found out [dx9screencapsrc](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/winscreencap/dx9screencapsrc.html?gi-language=c) uses DirectX to capture the screen in Windows but it seems that I can't select a certain window but rather can only provide the top-left coordinates, width and height of the capture area. Is there a workaround for capturing a window or another plugin for this?

I know that Windows isn't using the X Window but the [Desktop Window Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_Window_Manager) but I couldn't find anything in Gstreamer documentation directly related to that.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?